# Snowfall sfApply() is slower than apply()

Tags: r, snowfall

I am new to multicore in R and is trying out the snowfall package to test if it is possible to speed up the apply function.

Not sure what went wrong but my multi-core implementation of sfApply() is always about 2 times slower than the apply()

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Single core example - complete to about 1.3 seconds in my PC:

```
x=2000
y=10000
startTime <- proc.time()

randomX <- sample(1:100,x*y, replace=T)/100+0.5
randomMatrix <- matrix(NA,x,y)
randomMatrix[,] <- randomX
randomRetX <- apply(randomMatrix,2,cumprod)

endTime <- proc.time()
endTime-startTime
```

Snowfall Implementation - close to 3 secs in my PC:

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit( parallel=TRUE, cpus=4)
x=2000
y=10000

startTime <- proc.time()

randomX <- sample(1:100,x*y, replace=T)/100+0.5
randomMatrix <- matrix(NA,x,y)
randomMatrix[,] <- randomX
randomRetX <- sfApply(randomMatrix,2,cumprod)

endTime <- proc.time()

endTime-startTime
sfStop()
```

Comment: There is always some overhead in running in parallel: breaking the problem into pieces, communications between master and slaves, assembling the outputs. Maybe your problem is not large enough to benefit from parallel processing. I would not consider it for a task that only takes 1.3 seconds.

Comment: @SuperDisk, with your edit you have removed important information about computation times...

Comment: @flodel That was an accident. It's back now.

Comment: Try increasing the array size (x=8000) and the computation speed of afApply() is still multiple of apply(). so my feeling is that it is less of a overhead issue.